# Using multiple keys when the form is not focused

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want to use multiple keys to do different things while the form is not focused.
What I have done already: I have done only one key to print out a certain text when the form is not focused.

```
// DLL libraries used to manage hotkeys
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

const int F1_HOTKEY_ID = 1;
const int F2_HOTKEY_ID = 1;


public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Modifier keys codes: Alt = 1, Ctrl = 2, Shift = 4, Win = 8
    // Compute the addition of each combination of the keys you want to be pressed
    // ALT+CTRL = 1 + 2 = 3 , CTRL+SHIFT = 2 + 4 = 6...
    RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, F1_HOTKEY_ID, 0, (int)Keys.F1);
    RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, F2_HOTKEY_ID, 0, (int)Keys.F2);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == F1_HOTKEY_ID)
    {
        SendKeys.Send(txtBoxF1.Text + "{enter}");
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Now I want to use multiple keys and this is what I tried:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == F1_HOTKEY_ID)
    {
        SendKeys.Send(txtBoxF1.Text + "{enter}");
    }
    if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == F2_HOTKEY_ID)
    {
        SendKeys.Send(txtBoxF2.Text + "{enter}");
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

But that prints out both F1 and F2 texts when I want it to print out f2 individually.

Thank you.

Comment: `F1_HOTKEY_ID` == `F2_HOTKEY_ID`

Comment: @SamAxe can you expand on your comment because it is so vague.

Comment: `F1_HOTKEY_ID` and `F2_HOTKEY_ID` have the same value.